# What is the general algorithm for factoring a polynomial in $GF(n)$?

Tags: finite-fields

What should I start with when I want to factor a polynomial over $GF(n)$?

Should I start by finding it's irreducible polynomials? 
Say, I have $x^4+3x^3+4x+1$ and I want to factor it over $GF(5)$
What should I start with when I see a problem like "factor the $a_kx^k*\dots *a_0 $ over $GF(n)$"?

Comment: Check for roots.

Comment: [See here.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor–Zassenhaus_algorithm)

Comment: By Maple: Consider $\alpha$ be a root of ${\bf f}=x^4+3x^3+4x+1$ then the polynomial $\bf f$ over $GF(5)$ are factored as follows: $${\bf f}=  \left( x+4\,\alpha \right)  \left( x+3\,{\alpha}^{3}+4\,\alpha+4
 \right)  \left( x+4\,{\alpha}^{3}+{\alpha}^{2}+\alpha+1 \right) 
 \left( x+3\,{\alpha}^{3}+4\,{\alpha}^{2}+\alpha \right)
$$ Commands: 1)alias(alpha = RootOf(x^4+3*x^2+4*x+1)); 2)Factor(x^4+3*x^2+4*x+1, alpha) mod 5; Maybe helpful. ( Notice that $4\alpha =-\alpha$)